# How do I append a column to the end of another column in SQL

Tags: database, sqlite

I need to append the values from one column to another column using an SQL command and need some help with the syntax.

I have an image column with 'http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/' as the value for all fields in the table. I need to append to the end of this string the values from another column called "url". The url field has different values for each entry.

I was thinking something like:

```
SELECT image + url FROM 'films';
```

thanks for any help.

also, I need to do the reverse of this for another column, where I need to add the values from one column to the beginning to another column.

:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT image || url as imageUrl FROM 'films';
```

Comment: that's great. it outputted to the console though and did not update the table column. do i need to use UPDATE instead of SELECT? thanks :)

Comment: if you want to update something here is the syntax.. 
`update table set column3 = (column1 || column2);`

Comment: you want to append url to image column??

Answer (score 2):

try this:

For mysql :

```
select CONCAT(column1,column2) from table
```

OR when you are updating it use:

```
update table set column1= CONCAT(column1,column2)
```

Comment: thanks! I'm using sqlite and I get an error for: select CONCAT(image,url) from films;
no such function: CONCAT

Comment: this worked select image || url from films; but it didn't update the table. only outputted to the console. do I need to use the UPDATE command? thanks again

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is [`CONCAT`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-concat-function.htm).